# CSS: Format of font-family

Tags: css

Can anyone please tell me what does the below font family means?

Font-Family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the order of fonts to look for. The browser looks for "Segoe UI" first, if not available then fallback to "Segoe" and then the next in order. The first three are Windows fonts and not natively available in Apple, in which case will use Helvetica. If none were available, browser will display the default sans-serif font.

Answer (score 0):

The font that's being applied in the order..

1. Segoe UI
2. Segoe
3. Tahoma
4. Tahoma
5. Arial
6. sans-serif

If you want to use any other fonts, you can have your own font-family and use it.

Please check the below [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) for reference